# how to corectly call table function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, table-functions

I have table function which returns table of file names (`type t_file_list is table of clob;`) from .zip file (in BLOB format) the header is like:

```
  function get_file_list(
    p_zipped_blob in blob
   ,p_encoding in varchar2 := null
  )
    return t_file_list
  is
  .....
  end;
```

and I need to select these file names and for each call some procedure, but i cant find way to call `function get_file_list` correctly, I try this:

```
  for i in (select * from table(zip_util_pkg.get_file_list(ab_zipped_blob))) 
  loop
    .....
  end loop;
```

but it gives me some errors like ORA-22905 and PLS-00642. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to call table function correctly?

Comment: Is this type: `type t_file_list is table of clob;` declared in the package ? Or at the databae level ?

Comment: it is declared in both packages (in `zip_util_pkg` and in package where I need to call the function `get_file_list`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use SQL - you can do it entirely in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  p_files ZIP_UTIL_PKG.T_FILE_LIST;
BEGIN
  p_files := zip_util_pkg.get_file_list(ab_zipped_blob);
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_files.COUNT LOOP
    some_procedure( p_files(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me :-)